# Point Vim to updated Python version instead of recompiling

Tags: python, windows, vim

I'm beginning my journey into Vim and have run into a snag in attempts to turning it into my primary Python IDE. I'm using Vim v7.4 (latest) in addition to the python-mode plugin. Issue is that while this version of Vim is compiled with `+python/dyn` and `+python3/dyn`, it's pointing to `python32.dll` instead of `python34.dll`. I'm seeing all of this using the `:version` command.

Is there a way to target Vim to a newer version of Python without having to recompile it each time there is an update?

Comment: You do not need to recompile each time there is an update with `/dyn` bindings, but you definitely need to do so for minor version update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try renaming / symlinking `python34.dll` to `python32.dll`; if they are fully binary-compatible, this might work. But it is expected (and safer) to recompile Vim whenever your Python (or Perl, or any other language integration for that matter) version changes (which shouldn't be too often).

Comment: I created a symlink from `c:\Python32\` to `c:\Python34`, then renamed the Python binary to `python32.dll`. Unfortunately, this doesn't work. Where exactly does Vim look for the Python binary?

Comment: @user3665348 Vim does not look for Python library anywhere on its own AFAIK. If I am not mistaking it asks Windows to load library with specific name and Windows uses the list of directories in `%PATH%` environment variable. At least that is what I modify in Wine after I install Python to make Python bindings work.